# Moving a visual range to a new tabpage?

Tags: buffers, multiple-files, tabbed-user-interface

I would like to make a new tab page from part of the current text.
I would use visual selection, or other means to specify a text range.
Is there a single command like "New tab from selection"?

Writing this, I see the command is not exactly of `vim` style.

In that case, a small script may solve it.

Possibly there is a related plugin containing it?
 Here, one could reasonably hope for useful related features like creating a new file with derived name.

Comment: Simple way is map key to three command in row
`<,>y` - for yank visual range
`tabnew` - for creating new tab
`p` - for paste yanked text in first step

Answer (score 8):

#### Persisted

If you intend to persist the selected lines under a new filename (and it's complete lines), you can do:

```
:'<,'>w new-name | '<,'>delete _ | tabedit #
```

The `'<,'>` range is inserted automatically when you enter command-line mode from visual mode. `:write` can take a range, and afterwards, the filename is accessible via the *alternate file* (`#`) shortcut.

#### Unpersisted

If you just need a *scratch buffer* that is not written to disk, you have to *delete* and *put*:

```
d:tabedit +set\ buftype=nofile new-name | put!
```

If you use this frequently, I would write a custom command (that also saves and restores the original register contents) for it.

---

If you want *cloning*, not *moving*, drop the `:delete` / change `d` into `y`.